# How to restrict access by IP in a gRPC server?

Tags: node.js, grpc, api-gateway, grpc-node

I'm a beginner in gRPC and as my first challenge, I'm building a Node JS platform composed of some gRPC microservices (according to API-Gateway pattern). I would like to restrict all access from external sources - only the gateway itself will be able to reach my internal struct.

After  some time searching, I found out 3 ways to limit the access:

- 1 - HTTP authentication;
- 2 - Token authentication;
- 3 - TSL/SSL authentication;

My Gateway already has an auth mechanism - JWT middleware. I don't want to copy it for each microservice and generate a lot of code redundancy. 
I would like to get some way to filter my requests by IP in each internal microservice and allow or disallow its access. In a nutshell, I want to ensure that only the Gateway IP can access all internal microservices.

Here, the component diagram showing my initial architecture:
[image]

We can do it easily in an Express API:

```
// Express example
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.ip !== '1.2.3.4') { // Wrong IP address
    res.status(401);
    return res.send('Permission denied');
  }
  next(); // correct IP address, continue middleware chain
});
```

Is there some way to build something like that using gRPC?

Thank you very much.

Comment: My initial feeling was a certificate was the cleanest way, but sounds like you have reasons for not going that route.  I am not familiar with implementing a node server, but in the c# land, the ServerCallContext parameter that is on every rpc defined method has the ip of the caller.  you could filter that way, but then it would require configuration files or something to specify the acceptable IPs.  That is providing that node provides access to this as well

Comment: Hey there!

Well, unfortunately, ServerCallContext looks related to C# only :(
During my searches, I didn't find anything useful; following traditional architectures based on HTTP 1.1, the right way to get over my problem could be using JSON Web Tokens. In this way, I should implement a JWT validation mechanism in each service. Please, take a look in this picture:
https://www.globallogic.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/web-Figure-3.jpg
Notice that all internal services are handling a JWT mechanism for each request.
Thanks a lot.